# Compile tests in OS X Xamarin, run nunit on ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, xamarin, mono

I have a couple of integration/unit tests compiled in Xamarin (Mono /.NET 4.0). They are referencing a Xamarin Portable project (Mono 4.0) and are executing correct in Xamarin on Mac OS X. I would like to execute them on an ubuntu-machine.

I'm references `System.Runtime.Serialization` from the portable project and have included it as a reference in my nunit-test project. (version 4.0)

The tests are running correct on nunit-console on Mac OS x with the following `exec /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/bin/mono --debug $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/4.5/nunit-console.exe "$@"`

I copy the code to my Ubuntu machine and try to execute it. Output is either (`System.Runtime.Serialization` is set to copy-local)

```
Runtime Environment - 
  OS Version: Unix 3.5.0.54
 CLR Version: 4.0.30319.1 ( 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3) )

System.InvalidProgramException : Invalid IL code in System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute:get_Name (): IL_0000:
```

Or below (`System.Runtime.Serialization` is not set to copy-local)

```
Runtime Environment - 
OS Version: Unix 3.5.0.54
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.1 ( 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3) )

ProtoBuf.ProtoException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'
```

Is there something special that Xamarin does to be able to execute portable projects in a correct way that can't be done on Mono on Ubuntu?

I find it weird that nunit-console is referencing version 4.5 even if the project is build for 4.0

Comment: Do you have the referenceassemblies-pcl package installed? That should contain the PCL assemblies.

Comment: @MattWard yes! Have done `sudo apt-get install  referenceassemblies-pcl`